# Brainlabs adwords script remove firstpagemaxbid restriction

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

Can some body help me modify this script.
The purpose of the script is to change bids for the keywords based on average position. One of the assumptions that the script has is that it sets a firstpagebid for the keyword but it won't allow for the bid to go below the firstpagebid even if the position is too high.

Is there a way to remove this restriction? so basically if the new cpc calculated is lower than the first page bid then it allows for the new cpc to be lower than the firstpage bid.

```
/**
*
* Average Position Bidding Tool
*
* This script changes keyword bids so that they target specified positions,
* based on recent performance.
*
* Version: 1.5
* Updated 2015-09-28 to correct for report column name changes
* Updated 2016-02-05 to correct label reading, add extra checks and
* be able to adjust maximum bid increases and decreases separately
* Updated 2016-08-30 to correct label reading from reports
* Updated 2016-09-14 to update keywords in batches
* Updated 2016-10-26 to avoid DriveApp bug
* Google AdWords Script maintained on brainlabsdigital.com
*
**/

// Options

var maxBid = 14.50;
// Bids will not be increased past this maximum.

var minBid = 3.0;
// Bids will not be decreased below this minimum.

var firstPageMaxBid = 10.00;
// The script avoids reducing a keyword's bid below its first page bid estimate. If you think
// Google's first page bid estimates are too high then use this to overrule them.

var dataFile = "AveragePositionData.txt";
// This name is used to create a file in your Google Drive to store today's performance so far,
// for reference the next time the script is run.

var useFirstPageBidsOnKeywordsWithNoImpressions = true;
// If this is true, then if a keyword has had no impressions since the last time the script was run
// its bid will be increased to the first page bid estimate (or the firsPageMaxBid if that is smaller).
// If this is false, keywords with no recent impressions will be left alone.

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

// Advanced Options
var bidIncreaseProportion = 0.20;
var bidDecreaseProportion = 0.25;
var targetPositionTolerance = 0.3;

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

function main() {

  var fieldJoin = ",";
  var lineJoin = "$";
  var idJoin = "#";

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  /*var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(dataFile);
  if (!files.hasNext()) {
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(dataFile,"\n");
    Logger.log("File '" + dataFile + "' has been created.");
  } else {
    var file = files.next();
    if (files.hasNext()) {
      Logger.log("Error - more than one file named '" + dataFile + "'");
      return;
    }
    Logger.log("File '" + dataFile + "' has been read.");
  }*/

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
    // Get the current date/time
  var currentTime = new Date(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone(), "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var hourOfDay = currentTime.getHours();
  var dayOfWeek = days[currentTime.getDay()]; //Added on 9/21/2015
  // Prevent adjustments if not in between 8am and 11pm and Diffrent running time by date - Added on 9/21/2015 (important allows to set time based on day)
  switch (dayOfWeek) {
    case 'Monday':
    case 'Tuesday':
    case 'Wednesday':
    case 'Thursday':
    case 'Friday':
      if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay >= 21) {
        Logger.log("Not the Right Time");
        return;
      }
      break;
    case 'Saturday':
    case 'Sunday':
      if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay >= 18) {
        Logger.log("Not the Right Time");
        return;
      }
      break;
  }
        Logger.log("Right Time");

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  var labelIds = [];

  var labelIterator = AdWordsApp.labels()
  .withCondition("KeywordsCount > 0")
  .withCondition("LabelName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE 'Position '")
  .get();

  while (labelIterator.hasNext()) {
    var label = labelIterator.next();
    if (label.getName().substr(0,"position ".length).toLowerCase() == "position ") {
      labelIds.push(label.getId());
    }
  }

  if (labelIds.length == 0) {
    Logger.log("No position labels found.");
    return;
  }
  Logger.log(labelIds.length + " position labels have been found.");

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  var keywordData = {
    //UniqueId1: {LastHour: {Impressions: , AveragePosition: }, ThisHour: {Impressions: , AveragePosition: },
    //CpcBid: , FirstPageCpc: , MaxBid, MinBid, FirstPageMaxBid, PositionTarget: , CurrentAveragePosition:,
    //Criteria: }
  }

  var ids = [];
  var uniqueIds = [];

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  var report = AdWordsApp.report(
    'SELECT Id, Criteria, AdGroupId, AdGroupName, CampaignName, Impressions, AveragePosition, CpcBid, FirstPageCpc, Labels, BiddingStrategyType ' +
    'FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
    'WHERE Status = ENABLED AND AdGroupStatus = ENABLED AND CampaignStatus = ENABLED ' +
    'AND LabelIds CONTAINS_ANY [' + labelIds.join(",") + '] ' +
    'AND AdNetworkType2 = SEARCH ' +
      'AND Device NOT_IN ["HIGH_END_MOBILE"] ' +
        'DURING TODAY'
      );

  var rows = report.rows();

  while(rows.hasNext()){
    var row = rows.next();

    if (row["BiddingStrategyType"] != "cpc") {
      if (row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "Enhanced CPC"
          || row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "Target search page location"
          || row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "Target Outranking Share"
          || row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "None"
          || row["BiddingStrategyType"] == "unknown") {
        Logger.log("Warning: keyword " + row["Criteria"] + "' in campaign '" + row["CampaignName"] +
                   "' uses '" + row["BiddingStrategyType"] + "' rather than manual CPC. This may overrule keyword bids and interfere with the script working.");
      } else {
        Logger.log("Warning: keyword " + row["Criteria"] + "' in campaign '" + row["CampaignName"] +
                   "' uses the bidding strategy '" + row["BiddingStrategyType"] + "' rather than manual CPC. This keyword will be skipped.");
        continue;
      }
    }

    var positionTarget = "";

    if (row["Labels"].trim() == "--") {
      continue;
    }
    var labels = JSON.parse(row["Labels"].toLowerCase()); // Labels are returned as a JSON formatted string

    for (var i=0; i<labels.length; i++) {
      if (labels[i].substr(0,"position ".length) == "position ") {
        var positionTarget = parseFloat(labels[i].substr("position ".length-1).replace(/,/g,"."),10);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (positionTarget == "") {
      continue;
    }
    if (integrityCheck(positionTarget) == -1) {
      Logger.log("Invalid position target '" + positionTarget +  "' for keyword '" + row["Criteria"] + "' in campaign '" + row["CampaignName"] + "'");
      continue;
    }

    ids.push(parseFloat(row['Id'],10));
    var uniqueId = row['AdGroupId'] + idJoin + row['Id'];
    uniqueIds.push(uniqueId);

    keywordData[uniqueId] = {};
    keywordData[uniqueId]['Criteria'] = row['Criteria'];
    keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour'] = {};

    keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour']['Impressions'] = parseFloat(row['Impressions'].replace(/,/g,""),10);
    keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour']['AveragePosition'] = parseFloat(row['AveragePosition'].replace(/,/g,""),10);

    keywordData[uniqueId]['CpcBid'] = parseFloat(row['CpcBid'].replace(/,/g,""),10);
    keywordData[uniqueId]['FirstPageCpc'] = parseFloat(row['FirstPageCpc'].replace(/,/g,""),10);

    setPositionTargets(uniqueId, positionTarget);
  }

  Logger.log(uniqueIds.length + " labelled keywords found");

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  setBidChange();
  setMinMaxBids();

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

 /* var currentHour = parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone(), "HH"), 10);

  if (currentHour != 0) {
    var data = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var data = data.split(lineJoin);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      data[i] = data[i].split(fieldJoin);
      var uniqueId = data[i][0];
      if(keywordData.hasOwnProperty(uniqueId)){
        keywordData[uniqueId]['LastHour'] = {};
        keywordData[uniqueId]['LastHour']['Impressions'] = parseFloat(data[i][1],10);
        keywordData[uniqueId]['LastHour']['AveragePosition'] = parseFloat(data[i][2],10);
      }
    }
  }*/

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  findCurrentAveragePosition();

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  //Batch the keyword IDs, as the iterator can't take them all at once
  var idBatches = [];
  var batchSize = 5000;
  for (var i=0; i<uniqueIds.length; i += batchSize) {
    idBatches.push(uniqueIds.slice(i,i+batchSize));
  }

  Logger.log("Updating keywords");

  // Update each batch
  for (var i=0; i<idBatches.length; i++) {
    try {
      updateKeywords(idBatches[i]);
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log("Error updating keywords: " + e);
      Logger.log("Retrying after one minute.");
      Utilities.sleep(60000);
      updateKeywords(idBatches[i]);
    }
  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

 // Logger.log("Writing file.");
 // var content = resultsString();
 // file.setContent(content);

 Logger.log("Finished.");

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  // Functions

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function integrityCheck(target){
    var n = parseFloat(target, 10);
    if(!isNaN(n) && n >= 1){
      return n;
    }
    else{
      return -1;
    }

  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function setPositionTargets(uniqueId, target){
    if(target !== -1){
      keywordData[uniqueId]['HigherPositionTarget'] = Math.max(target-targetPositionTolerance, 1);
      keywordData[uniqueId]['LowerPositionTarget'] = target+targetPositionTolerance;
    }
    else{
      keywordData[uniqueId]['HigherPositionTarget'] = -1;
      keywordData[uniqueId]['LowerPositionTarget'] = -1;
    }
  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function bidChange(uniqueId){

    var newBid = -1;
    if(keywordData[uniqueId]['HigherPositionTarget'] === -1){
      return newBid;
    }

    var cpcBid = keywordData[uniqueId]['CpcBid'];
    var minBid = keywordData[uniqueId]['MinBid'];
    var maxBid = keywordData[uniqueId]['MaxBid'];

    if (isNaN(keywordData[uniqueId]['FirstPageCpc'])) {
      Logger.log("Warning: first page CPC estimate is not a number for keyword '" + keywordData[uniqueId]['Criteria'] + "'. This keyword will be skipped");
      return -1;
    }

    var firstPageBid = Math.min(keywordData[uniqueId]['FirstPageCpc'], keywordData[uniqueId]['FirstPageMaxBid'], maxBid);

    var currentPosition = keywordData[uniqueId]['CurrentAveragePosition'];
    var higherPositionTarget = keywordData[uniqueId]['HigherPositionTarget'];
    var lowerPositionTarget = keywordData[uniqueId]['LowerPositionTarget'];

    var bidIncrease = keywordData[uniqueId]['BidIncrease'];
    var bidDecrease = keywordData[uniqueId]['BidDecrease'];

    if((currentPosition > lowerPositionTarget) && (currentPosition !== 0)){
      var linearBidModel = Math.min(2*bidIncrease,(2*bidIncrease/lowerPositionTarget)*(currentPosition-lowerPositionTarget));
      var newBid = Math.min((cpcBid + linearBidModel), maxBid);
    }
    if((currentPosition < higherPositionTarget) && (currentPosition !== 0)) {
      var linearBidModel = Math.min(2*bidDecrease,((-4)*bidDecrease/higherPositionTarget)*(currentPosition-higherPositionTarget));
      var newBid = Math.max((cpcBid-linearBidModel),minBid);
      if (cpcBid > firstPageBid) {
        var newBid = Math.max(firstPageBid,newBid);
      }
    }
    if((currentPosition === 0) && useFirstPageBidsOnKeywordsWithNoImpressions && (cpcBid < firstPageBid)){
      var newBid = firstPageBid;
    }

    if (isNaN(newBid)) {
      Logger.log("Warning: new bid is not a number for keyword '" + keywordData[uniqueId]['Criteria'] + "'. This keyword will be skipped");
      return -1;
    }

    return newBid;

  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function findCurrentAveragePosition(){
    for(var x in keywordData){
      if(keywordData[x].hasOwnProperty('LastHour')){
        keywordData[x]['CurrentAveragePosition'] = calculateAveragePosition(keywordData[x]);
      } else {
        keywordData[x]['CurrentAveragePosition'] = keywordData[x]['ThisHour']['AveragePosition'];
      }
    }
  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function calculateAveragePosition(keywordDataElement){
    var lastHourImpressions = keywordDataElement['LastHour']['Impressions'];
    var lastHourAveragePosition = keywordDataElement['LastHour']['AveragePosition'];

    var thisHourImpressions = keywordDataElement['ThisHour']['Impressions'];
    var thisHourAveragePosition = keywordDataElement['ThisHour']['AveragePosition'];

    if(thisHourImpressions == lastHourImpressions){
      return 0;
    }
    else{
      var currentPosition = (thisHourImpressions*thisHourAveragePosition-lastHourImpressions*lastHourAveragePosition)/(thisHourImpressions-lastHourImpressions);
      if (currentPosition < 1) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return currentPosition;
      }
    }
  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function keywordUniqueId(keyword){
    var id = keyword.getId();
    var idsIndex = ids.indexOf(id);
    if(idsIndex === ids.lastIndexOf(id)){
      return uniqueIds[idsIndex];
    }
    else{
      var adGroupId = keyword.getAdGroup().getId();
      return adGroupId + idJoin + id;
    }
  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function setMinMaxBids(){
    for(var x in keywordData){
      keywordData[x]['MinBid'] = minBid;
      keywordData[x]['MaxBid'] = maxBid;
      keywordData[x]['FirstPageMaxBid'] = firstPageMaxBid;
    }
  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function setBidChange(){
    for(var x in keywordData){
      keywordData[x]['BidIncrease'] = keywordData[x]['CpcBid'] * bidIncreaseProportion/2;
      keywordData[x]['BidDecrease'] = keywordData[x]['CpcBid'] * bidDecreaseProportion/2;
    }
  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  function updateKeywords(idBatch) {
    var keywordIterator = AdWordsApp.keywords()
    .withIds(idBatch.map(function(str){return str.split(idJoin);}))
    .get();
    while(keywordIterator.hasNext()){
      var keyword = keywordIterator.next();

      var uniqueId = keywordUniqueId(keyword);

      var newBid = bidChange(uniqueId);

      if(newBid !== -1){
        keyword.setMaxCpc(newBid);
      }

    }
  }

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

  /*function resultsString(){

    var results = [];
    for(var uniqueId in keywordData){
      var resultsRow = [uniqueId, keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour']['Impressions'], keywordData[uniqueId]['ThisHour']['AveragePosition']];
      results.push(resultsRow.join(fieldJoin));
    }

    return results.join(lineJoin);
  }*/

  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the script increases the cpcBid when the current average position is too high, and decreases it when the position is too low.
But when the bid is decreased and the previous bid is more than firstPageBid, the new bid will not decrease below firstPageBid.

Remove

```
if (cpcBid > firstPageBid) {
    var newBid = Math.max(firstPageBid,newBid);
}
```

to allow your new bid to go lower than firstPageBid.